# Highlight default node in jquerytreeview on pageload using jquery

Tags: jquery, treeview

I am using jquery.treeview.js.
I need to highlight the node background color on page load.
On click I'm able to highlight background color and font, etc.

```
    $("a").css("backgroundColor", "");
    $("a").css("font-weight", "");
    $(this).css("backgroundColor", "grey");
    $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
    $.cookie("url", $(this));
```

Now I persists this object in a cookie and am able to read the same but unable to apply the css as it say the there is no such property.

```
    $.cookie("url").css("backgroundColor", "grey");
```

Why am I not getting a jQuery object back from the cookie?

Comment: alert(this.id) return empty
alert($(this).id) returns undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin try to set `$.cookie.json = true;`:

```
$.cookie.json = true;
...
$.cookie("url", $(this));
...
$.cookie("url").css("backgroundColor", "grey");
```

If this doesn't work you can read about object de-/serialization with JavaScript [here](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/11/25/serializing-javascript-objects-into-cookies/). Please be careful if you really need object serialization, the answer of dgvid is a better approach if you doesn't need the exact object before and after serialization. This is only the case if you extended the object with new variables/functions/listeners/... .

Comment: I didn't even know Klaus Hartl's plugin could do that. Great tip!

Comment: I didn't test this approach, but I added a link to JavaScript de-/serialization of objects. If my approach don't work, the one inside the link will do :)

Comment: Object i am able to get but it contains <font size=2> node </font>

Comment: And what do you expect? Maybe we can help you if you create an working example on JS Bin or JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because cookies hold strings, nothing else. Your node (technically an instance of a jQuery object) isn't a string. The article [Serializing Javascript Objects into Cookies](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/11/25/serializing-javascript-objects-into-cookies/) has a pretty good general overview of how to do what you want.

However, for your specific need, you might be able to do something much simpler that what's described in that article. If you know with certainty that the node you want to highlight will *always* have a non-empty id, you can just save the id, which is already a string, in the cookie. When you the id back from the cookie, you can use it as a selector to the get the object you want. For example:

```
// Works only if `this` has id attribute set:
$.cookie("url", this.id);


// Later...
var id = $.cookie("url");
$("#" + id).css("backgroundColor", "grey");
```

Comment: alert(this.id) return empty

Comment: I think you will want to try da_re's approach, then.